# You must `await server.start()` before calling `server.applyMiddleware()`

Tags: javascript, nodejs, apollo

he estado tratando de resolver dicho error. Pero cuando coloco la función await.starServer () la consola de Vs Code se tilda y no ejecuta el código. Lo he intentado correr con git bush here y lo mismo. Lo extraño es que cuando borro dicha función el código se ejecuta saltando el error que coloqué en el título. Me podrían indicar por favor como lo puedo solucionar o si encuentran algún error en el código. Yo no tengo experiencia desarrollando y debo cumplir con un tiempo estipulado para no perder una beca. Ah y me falto aclarar que lo estoy configurando con formato Ts.

```js
import { Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql"; 

@Resolver()

export class bookresolver {
    @Query (() => String)
    getAll () {
        
        return "All my books";
        
    };
    
}
```

Archivo server.ts

```js
import express from "express";
import "reflect-metadata";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import { bookresolver } from "./resolvers/book.resolver";


export async function startServer() {
     const app = express();
     
     const server = new ApolloServer({
         schema: await buildSchema({ resolvers: [bookresolver] }) 
     });
     
 start.Server()
     server.applyMiddleware({app, path: "/graphql" })
     
     return app;
     
};
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lee [ask]: describe en concreto cómo se da el error que expones en el título.

Comment: Revisa la línea de la importación. Si `resolver` es una carpeta de tu proyecto, lo correcto sería: `import ... from "./resolver/book.resolver";` Verifica eso, porque te estaría faltando el carácter `/` en la ruta. Saludos

Comment: Claro, por eso en mi comentario puse: *Si `resolver` es una carpeta*. Habrá que ver la estructura de tu aplicación, para identificar dónde está ubicado el módulo que quieres importar, al final todo se reduce a conocer la ruta relativa a dicho módulo. ¿Sabes dónde se ubica ese módulo en tu aplicación?

Comment: La carpeta se llama `resolver` (singular) y la estás importando como `resolvers` (plural). Verifica eso.

Comment: Podrías actualizar la pregunta con el nuevo código? Así podemos ayudarte mirando la última versión.

Comment: En el archivo `book.resolver.js` se está exportando por default el componente `book.resolver.`?

Comment: He votado +1 para que puedas entrar al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) de [es.so]. Mi zona horaria es GMT+2, pero cualquiera allí podría ayudarte u orientarte un poco más en la solución del problema. Es obvio que hay un problema bien sea en la forma en la que exportas el módulo o en la ruta al mismo, aunque todo luce correcto. Trataré de replicar tu programa, a ver si logro reproducir el error. Saludos

Comment: El error que tuve fue que la consola no me permitia saber el resultado de lo configurado en el código porque se llamaba dos veces a la misma función. Se resolvió quitando await startServer() y colocando server.start().

Comment: @GimenaPasten ponelo como respuesta, explicando que cambiaste!

Comment: @GimenaPasten, veo que encontraste la solución. Sugeriría que la colocaras como respuesta, para que el buscador no la siga incluyendo en las preguntas sin respuesta.